# using Boolean variable with a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, boolean

I have a 2D array populated with exam results. Array contains names. User inputs some name and the prog checks if that name equals to any other name stored in an array. If they match it prints out the whole row, that contains that name. If there is no such name it should print out an "error". I need to use a Boolean variable that checks if something was found. But the problem is I can't come up with the idea how to check that something was found in a loop. When I use this line:

```
boolean=namesmatch=namechk.equalsIgnoreCase(math[x][1]);
```

It only makes it right if user inputs first name, since x=0. If user inputs any other name it prints out the needed row and then an "error". What should I do to get rid of this "error"?

```
public class Math extends StudentCharts {

public Math(){
math = new String [3][3];
math[0][0]="math";      math[0][1]="Bill Gates";    math[0][2]="49";   
math[1][0]=math[0][0];  math[1][1]="John Doe";      math[1][2]="12";   
math[2][0]=math[0][0];  math[2][1]="Paul Allen";    math[2][2]="31";  }

public void prnt (String namechk){
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
   boolean namesmatch=namechk.equalsIgnoreCase(math[x][1]);

    for (x=0; x<3; x++) {
       if (namechk.equalsIgnoreCase(math[x][1])) {
           for (y=0; y<3; y++) {
        System.out.print(math[x][y]+" ");
    } } }
            if (!namesmatch) {
        System.out.println("error");
   } } }
```

this is the main class

```
public class Studentsarrays {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Math chr1 = new Math();

    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter full name, please");
    String namecheck = user.nextLine();
    chr1.prnt(namecheck); } }
```

Comment: What's going on with your braces there? Java isn't a lisp.

Comment: `boolean=namesmatch=namechk` is that a typo or is that what you actually have in your source code? Also, *"error"* does not help much. *What error* exactly are you getting?

Comment: You know you can do `if( namesmatch ) { ...`, right?

Comment: Also, `Math` is a somewhat inconvenient class name, because https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: Also, mutilating variable names like `prnt` and `namechk` used to be a perversion enjoyed by programmers of early `C`, but it is quite frowned upon nowadays.

Comment: I donno about the syntax and stuff.. But this might serve as a logic for your problem of "finding if at least one match was found".
Declare boolean namesmatch = false. In the inner for loop (y loop), set namesmatch = true. This would be set to true only if there was at least one match. And hence "if (!namesmatch)" statement will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.
Declare boolean namesmatch = false. In the inner for loop (y loop), set namesmatch = true. namesmatch would be set to true only if there was at least one match.

```
public class Math extends StudentCharts {

public Math(){
math = new String [3][3];
math[0][0]="math";      math[0][1]="Bill Gates";    math[0][2]="49";   
math[1][0]=math[0][0];  math[1][1]="John Doe";      math[1][2]="12";   
math[2][0]=math[0][0];  math[2][1]="Paul Allen";    math[2][2]="31";  }

public void prnt (String namechk){
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
   **boolean namesmatch=false;**

    for (x=0; x<3; x++) {
       **if (namechk.equalsIgnoreCase(math[x][1]))** {
           for (y=0; y<3; y++) {
        System.out.print(math[x][y]+" ");
        **namesmatch=true;**
    } } }
            if (!namesmatch) {
        System.out.println("error");
   } } }
```

Comment: You can't add markup to code btw. To emphasize the lines you changed, use comments.

Comment: @Potato Glad it served the purpose.
Please be kind enough to accept the answer :)